# How does this Perl shebang work? (For someone not coming from Perl)

Tags: python, perl, virtualenv, shebang

Could someone explain how this shebang works?

`#!/usr/bin/perl -e$_=$ARGV[0];exec(s/\w+$/python3/r,$_)`

I've seen it posted twice here but not coming from Perl it looks like magic to me.
I ask as I would like to adjust the directory to a python environment relative to the script.

i.e `#!../env/bin/python3` to (I'm just guessing here) `#!/usr/bin/perl -e$_=$ARGV[0];exec(s/\w+$/env/bin/python3/r,$_)`

Edit: I am trying to execute a simple ''Hello world" program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -e'$_=$ARGV[0];exec(s{\w+$}{exploit-env/bin/python3}r,$_)'

###############################

def main():
    print('Hello world')

###############################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: *Shebang* is *Nix* specific. How is the file named, and are there any others in the same *dir*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shebang handling isn't consistent across all systems<sup>[1]</sup>, but your system apparently apparently executes what the following shell command would execute (assuming the file containing the shebang is `/path/to/script`):

```sh
/usr/bin/perl -e'$_=$ARGV[0];exec(s/\w+$/python3/r,$_)' /path/to/script
```

(The path to the script might not be an absolute path —it might be relative to the current directory— but doesn't matter here.)

The script produces `/path/to/python3` from `/path/to/script` (by replacing the trailing "word" characters, which include letters, digits and underscore, but not `/`), then evaluates

```perl
exec('/path/to/python3', '/path/to/script')
```

The replaces the program running in the current process with a Python interpreter, passing the path to the script as an argument.

---

If I read between the lines correctly, you want to to run `/path/to/../env/bin/python3` instead of `/path/to/python3`. In order to achieve that, use either of the following:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/perl -e$_=$ARGV[0];exec(s/\w+$/..\/env\/bin\/python3/r,$_)
```

or

```sh
#!/usr/bin/perl -e$_=$ARGV[0];exec(s{\w+$}{../env/bin/python3}r,$_)
```

`/` needs to be escaped by `\` when `/` is used as the delimiter (first solution), but we can change the delimiter to produce a more readable result (second solution).

---

That shebang you presented causes the arguments to be absorbed. Replace the `$_` with `@ARGV` to pass them on.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/perl -e$_=$ARGV[0];exec(s{\w+$}{../env/bin/python3}r,@ARGV)
```

---

1. At least historically, some systems treat the entire sequence that follows `#!` as the path (i.e. no arguments allows), and some have very strict limits as to the length of the path.

Comment: I just realized this prevents the use of command line arguments. I tried ```#!/usr/bin/perl -e$_=join(' ', @ARGV);exec(s{\w+$}{../exploit-env/bin/python3}r,$_)``` but no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: Replace `$_` with `@ARGV`